# Internal Compiler Error during compile asp.net application in .NET framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

Showing errors: -

Internal Compiler Error (0xc0000005 at address 0028FDDC): likely culprit is 'CODEGEN'.
Internal Compiler Error: stage 'CODEGEN'
Internal Compiler Error: stage 'EMIT'
Internal Compiler Error: stage 'BEGIN'

error removed if we comment this code

```cs
private static string returnpagesofDOC(string path)
{
    object objMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Application objWord;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document objDoc;
    objWord = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    object fileName = path;

    objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(ref fileName,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing,
        ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing, ref objMissing);
    objDoc.Activate();

    string toatl = objWord.ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages).ToString();
    objDoc.Close();
    objWord.Quit();
    return toatl;
}
```

I have changed code but still same issue.

Comment: Do you still have the same error if you update to a framework which is rather more modern? .NET Framework 4.0 has been out of support for some time now - I'd *strongly* recommend that you update to a supported framework.

Comment: @JonSkeet I changed it to 4.5 and 4.8.1 but still same erro.

Comment: When does the issue occur - when you build the application, or when it's running? Can you reproduce it in a simple console application? (Basically, the easier you can make it for us to reproduce the problem, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you.)

Comment: this issue occur when build application.

Comment: Okay, so can you reproduce it in a simple console application? (Please make it as easy as possible for us to help you...)